# How to store an array for each user on my online app?

Tags: database, arrays

I am building a small online app (PHP/MySQL) where users can sign-up to become members, and inside the members area they have a list of quizzes they can take.

When displaying the list of quizzes for a given user (i.e. his browser just requested the page with the list), I need to know, for each quiz, whether or not the user already took it in the past. Cause if he did I'll display a checkmark aside to it. This is to help users keep track of their usage of the site.

**My problem**: So basically I need to store a list of "taken quizzes" for each user. But I am not sure about the best way of doing it.

**My solution so far**: Each quiz has an ID, so I am planning to store the list of "taken quizzes" for each user as a string (with values separated by commas) on my database. Then when I need to use it I read the string from the database and transform it into an array (and vice-versa for storing it back).

**UPDATE**: Apparently there are 2 viable options: 1) is to use the method I described above storing the array as a string, 2) is to create another MySQL table to store the quiz-id/user-id pairs. At this point I am wondering which solution is faster, should the site become popular. With the first option I will have the extra work of converting the string to an array and back, but after that I'll be searching on a small array (i.e., containing only the quizzes taken by the single user). With the MySQL solution I wouldn't need to convert strings back and forth, but I would need to search on a much larger dataset (i.e., all the quizzes taken by all the users). Any guess on which method is faster for a large number of users (e.g., 1000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use some thing like MySQL then try a similiar table structure:

TABLE: users
`user_id | user_name`

TABLE: quiz
`quiz_id | quiz_name`

TABLE: quiz_taken
`taken_id | user_id (FK) | quiz_id (FK) | timestamp`

Add an entry into the quiz_taken table for each participation in the quiz. Also, you can always add more coloumns to store more details.

Comment: Interesting. So to check if a user took a given quiz I would search the quiz_taken table with something like this: select * from quiz_taken where quiz_id=quiz AND user_id=user; and then if I got a row back it would mean he took it, else he didn't. Right?

Comment: Yes! That is one of the possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems OK to me. Or you could have a "quizs" table and a users_to_quizs table in the middle with foreign keys linking to both users and quizs. It's more relational database standard compliant, but it seems a bit complicated for what you wish to do !

I would stick with your solution ! (do you use PHP ?> in this case use implode/explode, you'll get what you wan really fast ! :-))

Comment: Yep using PHP, so yeah I'll use explode/implode for the conversion. Well, glad to know I was on the right track! Thanks.

Comment: I've used that solution a number of times myself. Just keep in mind future evolutions ! Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

check123's solution is good.
You don't want to store the entire quiz as an array
One addition

```
taken_id | user_id(FK) | quiz_id (FK) | timestamp | responses
```

Although a seperate table for responses is better, if you don't need to search the responses,
and to convert the quiz array,  use

```
$quiz_string=json_encode($quiz_array)

//Store $quiz in the responses field

//and to convert it back to array, use:
$quiz_array=json_decode($quiz_string_from_database)
```

Imploding and exploding is time consuming to build and slower. json works perfectly